# How to display the data one by one when its already finish fetching data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***HTML***

```
<div nz-row *ngIf="tempThermometer | async as temp">
<div *ngFor="let data of temp;let i = index;" nz-col nzXs="24" nzSm="12" nzMd="12" nzXl="8" nzXXl="6">
<nz-spin nzTip="Loading..." [nzSize]="'large'" [nzSpinning]="data.spinning">
                            <div echarts [options]="chartOption[i]" [autoResize]="true" style="height: 270px;"></div>
                          </nz-spin>
    </div>
    </div>
```

***TS***

```
 tempLoading = false;
  tempThermometer = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

getRoomList() {
    this.tempLoading = true;
    this.subscription = this.global
      .getData(`/conditions/latest?length=${this.pageSize}`)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.tempThermometer.next(Object.values(res['data'].map((obj: any) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            spinning: true
          };
        })));

        this.tempLoading = false;
        this.lineChart(this.tempThermometer.value);
      });
  }
lineChart(params?: any) {
    const _this = this;
    const list: any = [];

    params.forEach((param: any) => {
      const url = encodeURIComponent(param.sensor);
      // List URL
      list.push(`/conditions?length=${this.length}&sensor=${url}`);
    });
    // Promise requests
    const promises = list.map(
      (url: any) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
        this.subscription =  this.global.getData(url).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err: Error) => {
            return reject(err);
          });
        })
    );
    // Retrieve each data as per promise
    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
      const dataRoom: any = [];

      results.map((result) => {
        const date: any = [], temperature: any = [], humidity: any = [], newRoomData: any = [];
        const param = result['data'];
        const roomData = orderBy(param, ['date'], ['asc']);
        const room = roomData.slice(-1)[0];
        const timeEnd = room.date.slice(0, 19);
        const timeStart = subHours(timeEnd, 7);
        const dataHour = roomData.filter((data: TemplogRecord) => {
          return !isBefore(data.date, timeStart) && !isAfter(data.date, timeEnd);
        });

        // console.log(roomData);

        const hash = Object.create(null);

        dataHour.forEach((data: any) => {
          const key = data.date.slice(0, 13);

          if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = {
              sensor: data.sensor, temperature: data.temperature,
              humidity: data.humidity, date: key + ':00:00'
            };
            newRoomData.push(hash[key]);
          }
        });

        for (let x = 0; x < newRoomData.length; x++) {
          temperature.push(newRoomData[x].temperature);
          humidity.push(newRoomData[x].humidity);
          date.push(newRoomData[x].date);
        }

        dataRoom.push({
          date: date,
          humidity: humidity,
          temperature: temperature
        });
      });

      dataRoom.forEach((param: any, index: number) => {
        const option = {
          tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis',
            axisPointer: {
              animation: false
            },
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.8)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            padding: 10,
            textStyle: {
              color: '#000'
            },
            formatter: function (prm: any) {
              let rec = prm[0].name.slice(0, 10) + '<br/>' + prm[0].name.slice(11, 19) + '<br/>';

              for (let x = 0; x < prm.length; x++) {
                if (prm[x].axisIndex !== 1) {
                  rec += prm[x].marker + ' ' + prm[x].seriesName + ': '
                    + prm[x].data + _this.units['Celcius'] + '<br/>';
                } else {
                  rec += prm[x].marker + ' ' + prm[x].seriesName + ': '
                    + prm[x].data + '%' + '<br/>';
                }
              }
              return rec;
            }
          },
          ...this.echart.roomChart,
          dataZoom: [{
            type: 'inside',
            show: false,
            bottom: 0,
            width: '84%',
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
            zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
          },
          {
            type: 'slider',
            bottom: 0,
            show: false,
            width: '84%',
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
            zoomLock: false,
          }],
          xAxis: [{
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            scale: true,
            axisLine: {
              show: false
            },
            axisTick: {
              show: false
            },
            data: param.date.map((str: any) => {
              return format(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');
            }),
            splitLine: {
              show: true,
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(182, 202, 227)'
              }
            },
            axisLabel: {
              show: true,
              interval: 0,
              rotate: 90,
              formatter: ((data: any) => {
                return (data).slice(11, 19);
              })
            }
          },
          {
            gridIndex: 1,
            show: false,
            scale: true,
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            axisLine: {
              show: false
            },
            data: param.date,
            axisTick: {
              show: false
            },
            splitLine: {
              show: true
            }
          }],
          series: [{
            name: 'Humidity',
            data: param.humidity,
            type: 'line',
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgba(0, 101, 144, 1)'
            },
            markPoint: {
              type: 'Pin',
              data: [
                {
                  type: 'max',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(0, 101, 144)'
                  }
                },
                {
                  type: 'min',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgb(110, 151, 204)'
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            smooth: true,
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            yAxisIndex: 1
          },
          {
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: param.temperature,
            type: 'line',
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
            },
            markPoint: {
              type: 'Pin',
              data: [
                {
                  type: 'max',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(255, 5, 0)'
                  }
                },
                {
                  type: 'min',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgb(255, 87, 86)'
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            smooth: true
          },

          ]
        };
        this.chartOption.push(option);
        this.notScrolly = true;
        this.tempThermometer.value.filter((x: any) => params.map((y: any) => {
          if (y.id === x.id) {
            return y.spinning = false;
          }
        }));
      });
    });
  }
```

The problem here is, when it's loading it will fetch all the data before it will display them all.
What I want to do here is when the first item that already fetch, it will display while the others still fetching the data.

for example there's 5 items which is the area 1, area 2, area 3, area 4 and area 5.

when the area 1 already finish fetching the data then it will display it. while the other still loading/fetching.

like the area 1 already finish fetching then next the area 3 then area 2 then 5 then 4.

who ever finish fetching it will display automatically.

Comment: Can I ask why you're wrapping observables inside promises? You're losing a lot of the simplicity of RxJS - including the functionality you now need

Comment: Also, you've added a *lot* of code to your question. Do you want to process responses to `this.global.getData` as they arrive?

Comment: @KurtHamilton "Do you want to process responses to this.global.getData as they arrive?" - Yes sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in one of two ways. Neither would involve promises.

I'm not going to attempt to use your code example, as it is far too large, instead I will focus on the core of your problem - run an array of observables and process results as they are returned.

**1. Merge observables**

The RxJS `merge` function will run multiple observables together and call your subscribe callback with the individual values immediately.

```js
const observables: Observable<any>[] = this.getObservables();
merge(...observables).subscribe(result => {
  // individual results are logged here as soon as the observable returns them
  console.log(result);
}, err => {
  // empty error callback. 
  // This is here to allow us to add the complete callback
}, () => {
  console.log('complete');
});
```

**Pro**: simple to process results in the subscribe

**Con**: have to run complete code in the complete callback

**2. Process results in the pipe**

You can run the observables in parallel in a `forkJoin`. The subscribe will only be called when the final observable completes, but you can process results in individual `tap` operators.

```js
const observables: Observable<any>[] = this.getObservables()
  .map(x => x.pipe(
    // tap is run as soon as the observable is returned
    tap(result => console.log(result))
  ));
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(result => {
  console.log('complete');
});
```

**Pro**: simple complete handling in the subscribe

**Con** processing results in individual `tap` operators can get a bit messy

**Conclusion**

Both of these approaches are fairly equivalent. I would probably prefer the `forkJoin` approach, but I wanted to demonstrate the power and flexibility of RxJS by giving you a second example.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7rrmtn

The demo sets up 5 observables, each with a different delay. The observables are processed as the results are returned, and they both log when they complete.

As you can see, they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: How do I apply the forkJoin or merge observable? cause I'm using two api sir.

Comment: My example handles some arbitrary array of observables, it doesn't care where they come from. I kept my example simple so that it could be applied to any situation using observables.

Comment: For example, you could do `forkJoin([service1.makeCall(), service2.makeCall(), service3.makeCall()])`. They're just observables that you're running together.

Comment: how to fix this ```Type 'Promise<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>``` it try it like this ```const observables: Observable<any>[] = promises;```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **change detection strategy**
and run **detectChanges** function as soon as you update variable with the first data point